# The difference of 안 and 않

Tags: word-order

Korean's one of te hardest spelling is 안 and 않. So I want to know the rules in 안 and 않. Ex) 나는 안 할거야. Ex) 그는 그 일을 하지 않았다.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

않다 is used as verbs and secondary verbs and 안 is used as adverb,so they are differently used. 않다 is short of 아니하다 and 안 is short of 아니(that does not mean 아니하다`s 아니 it has slight differnce.) ex)아무것도 먹지 않는다, 안 먹는다.

Answer (score 1):

> 안 + verb = not + verb

He does not eat apple 그는 사과를 안 먹는다.

> 아니 한다 not do => 않다=않아요=않는다, not did => 않았다.

He does not clean the room 방을 청소하지 않는다.

He did not eat 먹지 않았다.

> 아니다 not is => 않다=않아요, not was => 않았다.

I do not want to be tall 나는 키 크고 싶지 않다.

Answer (score 1):

Re-[translation](/questions/tagged/translation) of the original post by 김성훈 at
[here](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/a-hard-translation-question/4771#4771)

> They differ in usage; 않다 functions as either a verb or a secondary verb while 안 functions as an adverb.
>   않다 is abbreviate from 아니하다 while 안 is from 아니; therefore, 않다 and 안 can be used in place of 아니하다 and 아니, respectively, in a sentence to make it shorter.
>   
>   
>   Replacing 아니하다 with 않다 
>   아무 말도 **아니하다**. => 아무 말도 **않다** : ~ not say anything.
>   
>   먹지 **아니하다** => 먹지 **않다** : ~ not eat ~. 
>   
>   Replacing 아니 with 안:
>   **아니** 먹다 => **안** 먹다 : ~ not eat ~. 
>   소리가 **아니** 들리다 => 소리가 **안** 들리다 ~ can not hear the sound.