# A hard translation question

Tags: korean-to-english

‘않다’는 동사 또는 보조 용언으로 기능하고, ‘안’은 부사로 기능하는 말로, 그 쓰임새가 다릅니다. ‘않다’는 ‘아니하다’의 준말이고, ‘안’은 ‘아니’의 준말입니다. 따라서 ‘아니하다’를 줄여 쓸 자리에는 ‘않다’를 쓰고, ‘아니’를 줄여 쓸 자리에는 ‘안’을 씁니다. 보기를 들어 ‘아무 말도 아니하다. 먹지 아니하다’의 ‘아니하다’를 줄일 때에는 ‘아무 말도 않다, 먹지 않다’와 같이 ‘않다’를 쓰고, ‘아니 먹다, 소리가 아니 들리다’의 ‘아니’를 줄일 때에는 ‘안 먹다, 소리가 안 들리다’와 같이 ‘안’을 씁니다.

I need to translate this. I have attempted a translation by myself, however I am not native to English, so I am asking here for some assistance.

않다 is used as verbs and secondary verbs and 안 is used as adverb,so they are differently used. 않다 is short of 아니하다 and 안 is short of 아니(that does not mean 아니하다`s 아니 it has slight differnce.) ex)아무것도 먹지 않는다, 안 먹는다 this is my undone translation

Comment: Perhaps you could include your attempt at a translation, or point out which bits are particularly difficult? That way someone can help even if they don't have time to translate and explain the whole thing.

Comment: @topo morto did it!!!

Answer (score 2):

Translation:

They differ in usage; 않다 functions as either a verb or a secondary verb while 안 functions as an adverb.
않다 is abbreviated from 아니하다 while 안 is from 아니; therefore, 않다 and 안 can be used in place of 아니하다 and 아니, respectively, in a sentence to make it shorter.


Replacing 아니하다 with 않다 
아무 말도 **아니하다**. => 아무 말도 **않다**

먹지 **아니하다** => 먹지 **않다**

Replacing 아니 with 안:
**아니** 먹다 => **안** 먹다
소리가 **아니** 들리다 => 소리가 **안** 들리다

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should not ignore is that 동사 and 형용사 are collectively called 용언. I would translate that paragraph as the following, although it could sound awkward:

않다 functions as a main verb or an auxiliary verb/adjective whereas 안 does as an adverb; these two are different in usage. 않다 is the abbreviation of 아니하다, and 안 is that of 아니. Thus, 않다 is used where 아니하다 is to be shortened, and 안 is used where 아니 is to be shortened. To illustrate, 아무 말도 아니하다 and 먹지 아니하다 are shortened to 아무 말도 않다 and 먹지 않다, respectively; 아니 먹다 and 소리가 아니 들리다 are shortened to 안 먹다 and 소리가 안 들리다, respectively.